# facebook share a page in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

When I click 'Share', then it opens facebook share page in a new tab. I want to show temp.jpg in left bar in this page. How to do this?

test.aspx

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <!-- AnythingSlider #1 -->
    <ul id="slider1" style="width: 778px; height: 452px; background:#fff;">
        <li>
            <div style="float: left; padding-right: 35px; padding-left:50px;">
                <img src="../../img/temp.jpg" style="width: 264px;
                    height: 377px; border: none;" />      
                <uc:DownloadControl ID="DownloadControl1" runat="server" PageParameters="1" />
            </div>                
        </li>
        <li>
        <uc:DownloadControl ID="DownloadControl2" runat="server" PageParameters="2" />
...
```

DownloadControl.ascx

```
<div style="float: left">
   <a class="icerik" id="facebookShare" runat="server" target="_blank">
    <img border="0" src="images/facebook.jpg" alt="Resorts"
        title="Hotels & Resortss" /> Share </a>
```

DownloadControl.ascx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
 facebookShare.HRef = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.test.com/test.aspx";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make FRAMES http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp and change your link's `target="_blank"` to `target="framename"`